# Blender do not want to start

Tags: blender

blender do not want to start, when i wanted to run it via cmd it gaves me this output:

```
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSSIBLE solution:
"This issue could be seen due to User Account Control (UAC) feature enabled on Windows Vista or Windows 7 operating system.

UAC is enabled by default in Windows Vista and Windows 7, as a result, you might encounter some compatibility problems with different applications that have not yet been updated for the Windows UAC component

Temporarily disabling UAC may resolve the exception access issue, however, turning off UAC reduces the security of your system. We do not recommend leaving UAC disabled. " Found this at: http://java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml

Extra info: I have had experience with this issue before, just not on blender. There wasn't really a solution in my case, so I ended up having to reinstall the program, which worked. If the solution above doesn't work, try saving your files on blender, reinstalling it, then putting all your files back.
There is also someone who has had this exact same error, there is some information there that might help you: http://steamcommunity.com/app/365670/discussions/0/541906989401659580/?l=english
Hope this helps :D

Comment: TO be honest thats not the issue because i have uac disabled permamently

Comment: Hmm I don't know then, this error isn't uncommon and there seems to be no 100% working solution. Again, the best one I can currently offer is save your files, reinstall blender, and put your previous files back. Try copying the error code and pasting it into a search engine, that's what I did. Try that for now, I'll be trying to find something as well. Another idea: try running as administrator.

Comment: I upgraded win7 to win 10 and it works fine now. Thanks for help.